# How to create common Zend select object?

Tags: zend-framework

I would like to create a common class for Zend's select object and then after want to use that class's method by adding additional required fields, joins, wheres, orders, limit etc.

Here I am just describing what I am thinking.

```
class Model_Commonselect
{
     public function Commonselect()
     {
          //Zend select object with preset from table and join
          //return common select object
     }
}
```

From above structure I would like to set some pre-required `FROM` and `JOIN` in base function then then want to return that `select` object and further want to add additional `JOIN`, `WHERE`, `ORDER`, `LIMIT` etc.

Can anyone suggest such structure to use?

Answer (score 0):

zend already has a structure for that

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_City extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    protected $_name = 'city';// this is the tables name

    public function findByName($name){
        $select = $this->select()->where('name = ?',$name);
        return $this->fetchRow($select);
    }
}
```

UPDATE : @NullPointer

this is just a sample code, u can use the `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` class as a base and create your own from scratch or just override its `select()` method and make your own.

```
class Application_Model_MySelect extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    public function mySelect()
    {
        $select = parent::select(false);
        $select
            ->from('my table')
            ->join('some other table')
            ->where('something');

        return $select;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I would like to have a common method in which I can specify few tables with joins and the method should return an object which can further be edited with new joins, wheres, orders, limits etc. Not only for one table only.